# Converting URLWithString to NSURLConnection

Tags: json, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I am new to iOS development and I am trying to retrieve some data from server.
I have used:

```
 NSData *jsonDataString = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

which is freezing my app's UI. I put it dispatch but this causes other issues.

How to convert this one to NSRULConnection which will reply NSData like URLWithString?

Thank you

Comment: What "other issues" did you see when it was in a dispatch block?

Comment: I am loading some annotations in a map. After "refreshing"(which means remove all pins from map, download data from the server,create pins and placed them on the map) the annotations doesn't show in the map until I tapped the map once(switching tabs also shows annotations). If I do this without dispatch is working fine

Comment: Once you have finished downloading the file, switch back to the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was dispatching [self function1[self function2[self function3]]]; where the function3 was the json request. After dispatching only function3 the result was fine